# Удаление одинаковых элементов списка в цикле

Tags: python, список, python-3.8

Например есть список `S = [1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 7]`. Во время цикла программа вычисляет повторяющиеся элементы, выводит их на экран, и затем должна удалить их из списка. Я пробовал так:

```
S = [1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 7]
S.sort()
i = 0
for i in S:
    a = S.count(i)
    if a > 1:
        print(i,end=' ')
        S.remove(i)
    i += 1
```

Однако, программа удаляет только один элемент первого вхождения. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как за один раз удалить все одинаковые элементы в списке.

Comment: В чем проблема? Переменная `S` после выполнения у меня выглядит как `[1, 5, 7]`.

Comment: S = [1, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 7] а если список будет вот такой ?

Comment: а как должна программа выводить повторяющиеся элементы - если 5ка повторяется 10 раз - это надо вывести 1 раз или 9 раз?

Comment: 1 раз. Суть программы вывести повторяющиеся элементы всего по 1 разу

Comment: OMG. Используйте enumerate. Цикл проходит не через все элементы.

Comment: Еще не знаю, что такое enumerate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

например можно сделать так, правда это немного извращённо:

**вариант 1:**

```
S = [1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 7]

data = sorted(S)

S_new = [data[0]]
S_dublicated = set()

for i in range(1, len(data)):
    if data[i] == data[i-1]:
        S_dublicated.add(data[i])
    else:
        S_new.append(data[i])

print(*S_dublicated)
print(*S_new)
```

**вариант 2:**

```
S = [1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 7]

S_new = set()
S_dublicated = set()

for obj in S:
    if obj in S_new:
        S_dublicated.add(obj)
    S_new.add(obj)

# for obj in S:
#     S_dublicated.add(obj) if obj in S_new else S_new.add(obj)

print(*S_dublicated)
print(*S_new)
```

Answer (score 4):

Проблема в том, что у вас перебор списка и удаление из него идут в одном месте.

---

А так, можно через множество прогнать список. В множестве не может быть дубликатов:

```
items = [1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 7]
items = list(set(items))
print(items)
# [1, 5, 7]
```

Либо удаляйте, но в обратном порядке:

```
items = [1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 7]

for i in reversed(items):
    if items.count(i) > 1:
        items.remove(i)

print(items)
# [5, 1, 7]
```

Кст, вместо `reversed` можно использовать `list`, тогда будет создана копия списка и это тоже будет работать, т.к. удаление будет из исходного списка, а перебор у копии списка:

```
for i in list(items)
# или
for i in items[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Date: October 26th, 2020.
'''
Задача: один раз вывести дублирующиеся элементы.
'''
array=[1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 7]
_temp=set(array)
print(f"array: {array}.")
print(f"_tmp: {_temp}.")
# _temp - набор уникальных значений array.
for item in _temp:
    count=array.count(item)
    if count > 1:
        print(f"Значение {item} дублировалось {count} раз(а).")
array=list(_temp)
del _temp
print("Новый список:", '\n', array)
```