# При удалении элемента из списка удаляется следующий

Tags: python, индексация

Список не изменял. Принт выводит правильную индексацию, но при попытках удалить элемент, индекс перескакивает на 1 вперёд.

```
n=int(input())
jos=list(range(1,n+1))
print (jos[0],jos[1],jos[2],jos[3])
jos.pop(jos[1])
print(jos)
```

вывод:

```
10
1 2 3 4
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1195418/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b5?rq=1

Comment: Код в вопросе должен быть в виде текста, а не скриншотом.

Comment: Прошу более не задавать вопросов в которых код будет представлен скриншотом. Вы можете вставить код, выделить его и нажать `ctrl+k` или вставить код и отделить его ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пользуйтесь на здоровье, рекомендую вам хотя бы гуглить метод перед тем как задавать вопрос.

```
num = int(input())
l = list(range(1, num+1))

print(l[0], l[1], l[2], l[3])
l.pop(1)
print(l)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас вижу в сравнении. Конечно, гуглил, тут и так всё теперь понятно, но прошла неделя с начала изучения языка - затупил, а рядом спросить некого.